# Separate multi-line scraped text into separate lists

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using BS4 to scrape text. My current output of the text has 7 different fields that I would like to put into 7 different lists. My code is as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


urlYears = ['2012']
for year in urlYears:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + "2012" + "_NFL_Draft").content,"html.parser")
    table = soup.select_one("table.wikitable.sortable")

    for row in table.select("tr + tr"):
        tds=row.text
        print (tds)
```

The printed output will show up like this:

```
7^
252
St. Louis Rams
Richardson, DarylDaryl Richardson 
RB
Abilene Christian
Lone Star




7^
253
Indianapolis Colts
Harnish, ChandlerChandler Harnish 
QB
NIU
MAC
```

How can I create lists from each of these? The ultimate goal is to export as a CSV.

Answer (score 0):

A trivial approach would be to just [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the text at the newlines?

```
import os

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_NFL_Draft").content, "html.parser")
table = soup.select_one("table.wikitable.sortable")

for row in table.select("tr + tr"):
    tds=row.text.split(os.linesep)
    print tds
```

Yields

```
[u'', u'', u'1', u'1', u'Indianapolis Colts', u'Luck, AndrewAndrew Luck\xa0\u2020', u'QB', u'Stanford', u'Pac-12', u'', u'']
[u'', u'', u'1', u'2', u'Washington Redskins', u'Griffin III, RobertRobert Griffin III\xa0\u2020', u'QB', u'Baylor', u'Big 12', u'from St. Louis\xa0[R1 - 1];', u'2011 Heisman Trophy winner\xa0[N 2]', u'']
[u'', u'', u'1', u'3', u'Cleveland Browns', u'Richardson, TrentTrent Richardson\xa0', u'RB', u'Alabama', u'SEC', u'from Minnesota\xa0[R1 - 2]', u'']
[u'', u'', u'1', u'4', u'Minnesota Vikings', u'Kalil, MattMatt Kalil\xa0\u2020', u'OT', u'USC', u'Pac-12', u'from Cleveland\xa0[R1 - 3]', u'']
[u'', u'', u'1', u'5', u'Jacksonville Jaguars', u'Blackmon, JustinJustin Blackmon\xa0', u'WR', u'Oklahoma State', u'Big 12', u'from Tampa Bay\xa0[R1 - 4]', u'']
...
```

Hth
dtk

**Edit:** you can actually just [`.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#unicode.splitlines) to have Python handle the newlines correctly. Saves the `os` import as well.